# Where should you store oAuth token data in a node.js app

Tags: node.js, security, oauth-2.0, storage

I am creating a node.js app to run on a server, background service that is polling an API.

I need to use an OAuth token to make API requests. Once I have obtained the token and have both it and the refresh token what is the standard (and secure) way of persisting this locally so I can restart the app and the token later?

Answer (score 1):

For a background service the most common option is to use client credentials flow and just store tokens in memory.

There is a component called keytar that will manage persistemt nodejs secure OS token storage  - it is most commonly used for desktop Uis - see these resources of mine:

- [Code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.desktopsample.final/blob/master/src/plumbing/oauth/tokenStorage.ts)
- [Write up](https://authguidance.com/2018/01/26/final-desktop-sample-overview/)

Comment: Memory is fine until the app closes or server restarts. I will take a look at keytar. Thank you